# Preserving Relationships on imported data

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'll start with the background story before explaining the problem with my code. I'm using MS Access 2010. I've been able to import a table of data with two columns. Then I was able to curate the data by adding fields with appropriate values to the imported table. Now, I need to take the curated table and integrate it into my data base. However, I cannot use any of Microsofts built in queries as none of these appear to be able to do what I need. The integration breaks the table apart, yes, but it needs to **preserve the relationships** of the data in each record.

To this end I've been writing some code in VBA:

```
Function IntegrateNIRData(curatedTable, queryRecords)

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsCuratedTable, rsDBRecords As DAO.Recordset
    Dim iCount As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rsCuratedTable = db.OpenRecordset(curatedTable, dbOpenTable) 'open the recordset for use (table, Query, SQL Statement)
    Set rsDBRecords = db.OpenRecordset("NIR_Samples_verify", dbOpenDynaset, dbExecDirect, dbOptimisticValue)

    With rsCuratedTable
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            Do While Not .EOF
                ' Rest of your code here.
                rsDBRecords.AddNew
                    'Assign Fields here.
                    rsDBRecords![Product Name] = rsCuratedTable![productName]
                    rsDBRecords![Lot Number] = rsCuratedTable![lotNumber]
                    rsDBRecords!counts = rsCuratedTable![counts]
                    rsDBRecords![subsets] = rsCuratedTable![subsets]
                    rsDBRecords![Date Taken] = rsCuratedTable![dateTaken]
                rsDBRecords.Update
                rsDBRecords.Bookmark = rsDBRecords.LastModified
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    rsCuratedTable.Close 'Close the recordset
    rsDBRecords.Close 'Close the recordset

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Cleanup after ourselves
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "MS Access has generated the following error" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & _
    Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Source: IntegrateNIRData" & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & _
    Err.Description, vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit

End Function
```

The Function hangs on this line, the second OpenRecordset:

```
Set rsDBRecords = db.OpenRecordset("NIR_Samples_verify", dbOpenDynaset, dbExecDirect, dbOptimisticValue)
```

To my understanding this may have something to do with Workspaces and the Jet engine not accepting a ms query that spans multiple tables. Of course, I could also be way off. Any advice at this point would be greatly appriciated.

Update:

Several of you have asked similar questions so I felt I should clarify the following:

1) NIR_Samples_verify is an MS access select query that generates a table of records from several of the tables in the database.

2) I keep getting two errors depending on what I set the RecordsetOptionEnum and LockTypeEnum to in the OpenRecordset method. 
One is Error Number 3027 Database is Read-Only
Two is Error Number 3001 Invalid Arguement

3) To my understanding the rest of the code should be fine, it is just the OpenRecordset method that is causing the problem.

Update 2:

I am thinking that maybe access is not capable of doing what I would like. Let me illustrate. If I had two tables both with primary keys and these keys are referenced in a third table that links the two tables causing a many-to-many relationship, then the code would have to not only add the new data to the two tables, but also generate an appropriate record in the third table to maintain the relationship in the data. Hope that makes since. I do appriciate the help and experience.

Update 3:

Have been searching the net and found the following:

From [this post](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html) it says the query is only updatable when:
1) It is based on a single table.
2) It is based on a query based on a single table. 
3) It is based on a query based on tables with a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: On a side note, in the vba editor I tried to enter rsDBRecords!Counts = rsCuratedTable![Counts] but the editor kept changing the word 'Count' (upper case) to 'count' (lower case). Would this cause a problem?

Comment: Why can't you just run a query along the lines of "insert into... select from..." ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Because it only adds to "a table" not "multiple tables" while preserving relationships.

Comment: What is `NIR_Samples_verify` ? Whether it's updateable will depend on what it is exactly: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html

Comment: NIR_Samples_verify is an MS access select query that generates a table of records from several of the tables in the database.

Comment: Does it only work if the query only acts on one table?

Comment: That all depends on exactly what type of query it is. The link I posted has the information you need: without seeing your query we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my hunch was correct. The problem had to do with MS Access having updatable and non-updatble queries (See my edits of the question). The main problem was not only does Microsoft not make this information apparent, but there is no master list on their site either. Thank you everyone for the help. Feel free to see [this article](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what the contents of `NIR_Samples_verify` are, I'd be highly suspicious of the `dbExecDirect`

From the help file

**dbExecDirect**

> "Runs a query by skipping SQLPrepare and directly calling
>   SQLExecDirect (ODBCDirect workspaces only). Use this option only when
>   you’re not opening a Recordset based on a parameter query. For more
>   information, see the "Microsoft ODBC 3.0 Programmer’s Reference." "

I don't see you supplying any parameters.

**-- Edit --**

Typically I'll open a record set like this

```
Set rsDBRecords = db.OpenRecordset("select bar from foo where bar > 10", _
                                    dbOpenDynaset, _
                                    dbSeeChanges)
```

(Especially if I want to alter the data init)

Hopefully that'll move you further in your project.

**-- Edit 2 --**

It sounds like `NIR_Samples_verify` is to complicated to be edited. Actually, given that it is a join of multiple tables doing an `Add` on it doesn't make much sense, and `Update` MIGHT make sense in some cases.

Your ultimate solution is really going to be doing multiple Adds on multiple record sets (one for each table being referenced in `NIR_Samples_verify`); much like if you were entering the data into the DB by hand. You add the records that aren't dependant on anything else first (remembering to grab keys to use in the dependant tables).

Comment: Was just taking that code at face value from another response. Was not sure if the dbExecDirect was necessary or not, but the dbOptimisticValue is there so that it is not dbReadOnly (the default). I'm not sure what these setting should be, but I know the defaults do not work.

Comment: Setting it to dbSeeChanges causes the Database is Read-Only error.